# Suggestion to moderators: inform newer users that posts may migrate

Tags: discussion, migration

I have recently posted a question here on meta, that belonged elsewhere. Not knowing that moderators could (and would) automatically migrate my question over to the correct (meta) site, I flagged my own for deletion ("incorrect for this site"), and posted the right place.

Then I got told off for reposting, which is correct. But I was actually in good faith, tried to do it right.

Hence my question: if admins could post a little note like "do *NOT* post same question, it will be auto-migrated to the correct forum". It would be helpful for less-experienced users.

Comment: You don't get a notification when your post is moved?

Comment: Yes I do, but before I saw that I had already flagged for deletion and posted the correct place. So events crossed. I would never have posted, if I knew / had been told that post was migrated - and thereby giving admins more work to remove duplicate.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. How would the "little note by admins" be different than the notification you received?

Comment: I was told by admins "please do not cross post same question that is already migrated". Something like that. But I didn't know migration was possible, and I certainly do not want to do things that admins don't find right.

Comment: Also, a note about migration: unless the questions are obviously off-topic on the source site and [good enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91411/241919) on the target site, questions rarely get migrated at all. Thus, "*it will be auto-migrated to the correct forum*" is also false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several problems collided here.

1. You [originally asked the question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72486035/what-is-best-stack-site-to-ask-about-an-api-address-not-function), where it was—I should hope—self-evidently off-topic, since it is not about programming. There was a comment left there suggesting it was off-topic, and several close votes. You never flagged that question for removal. It was automatically migrated to Meta Stack Overflow (this site).
2. That comment I mentioned, the first one left on your question on Stack Overflow, which got migrated with the question here to Meta Stack Overflow… that comment contained incorrect or at least misleading advice. While questions asking for a site recommendation are explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow, and while they are explicitly on-topic for Meta Stack Exchange, they are *also* on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow. The comment's implication that your question needed to be asked on Meta Stack Exchange was wrong. Certainly, at the time the comment was left, when the question was asked on Stack Overflow, asking on Meta Stack Exchange would have been a better choice. But there is nothing wrong with asking on Meta Stack Overflow, which is what effectively happened when your question got migrated here.
3. Why did your question not get migrated directly to Meta Stack Exchange? Well, the proximate reason is because normal users cannot migrate questions from Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Exchange. They can only migrate them from Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Overflow, because that's the *normal* thing that should be done. And that's what happened, which is fine, as noted in the previous item. So the deeper reason is that the question didn't *need* to be migrated to Meta Stack Exchange, because it was just fine on Meta Stack Overflow.
4. As your question sat on Meta Stack Overflow, it started accumulating close votes that were completely invalid. Those two close-voters chose this reason:

   > Not suitable for this site → This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](http://stackexchange.com/sites), within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

   Do you see the problem? I think it is obvious. Your question—indeed, *any* question asking for a suggestion of what Stack Exchange site to ask a question on—is, obviously, about "the software that powers the Stack Exchange network", which makes your question emphatically on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow and the close reason completely invalid.

   No, I don't know why people vote to close questions here on Meta Stack Overflow for invalid reasons. I agree that that is confusing. Unfortunately, it is not a system problem.
5. Presumably, you took the (incorrect) close votes on your Meta Stack Overflow question, combined with the still-visible comment suggesting Meta Stack Exchange, to mean that the question should have been asked on Meta Stack Exchange, and you re-posted it there. Well, that would have been fine, except:

   - As noted, the question was fine on Meta Stack Overflow and didn't need to be moved to Meta Stack Exchange.
   - If you *are* going to re-ask a question somewhere else, that is also fine, as long as it is on-topic there (and it was on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow), but you need to *delete the original question*. You could have done that easily, as there were no answers posted to the one on Meta Stack Overflow that would have blocked deletion. **In the future, if you're going to re-ask a question elsewhere in hopes of receiving better answers, you need to *delete the original copy*.**

> I flagged my own for deletion ("incorrect for this site")

I cannot see any evidence of your having done this. Such an action should leave a trace in the question's timeline for a moderator, but I cannot see it. So I don't know what you're referring to here, or what system feature you tried to use.

> Then I got told off for reposting, which is correct. But I was actually in good faith, tried to do it right.

Hmm, "told off"…not really. At least, not by my standards. (It gets a *lot* worse. :-D) The comment I posted was simply:

> Since this was asked on MSE, and answered there, I'm deleting this copy. Do not cross-post questions to multiple Stack Exchange sites.

which implicitly referenced an earlier comment left by [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) that contained the actual link to the question on MSE.

The comment wasn't presuming bad faith. Its only real purpose was to explain (both to you, the author, and to future viewers) why I (as a moderator) immediately deleted a question that was, on face, completely fine and definitely on-topic.

If it helped to teach you or reinforce the fact that cross-posting questions on multiple sites is something which should not be done, then that's only a side benefit. As noted above, you didn't *exactly* do everything right: you should have *deleted* the abandoned version of the question here on MSO after you re-posted on MSE. Since you didn't [know to] do that, I did it for you. I would say the system is working as intended.

> Hence my question: if admins could post a little note like "do NOT post same question, it will be auto-migrated to the correct forum". It would be helpful for less-experienced users.

Isn't that…*exactly* what I did? Except that I didn't mention migration, since I was too late: you'd already re-posted it over on MSE.

Had I seen it earlier, I would have either migrated the question myself directly without needing to leave a comment (not in this case, since the question didn't *need* migrating, since it wasn't off-topic for MSO), or I would have removed the misleading comments and cleared the incorrect close votes. Unfortunately, I was busy implementing a "burst" write mode in a kernel driver. I only had a chance to look [while waiting for the code to compile](https://xkcd.com/303/). (Yes, it's working well; thanks for asking!)

Comment: THANK you for the explanation and effords. I will follow your advise in future cases. Lesson learned, tutorial restudied.